# Qual é o erro nesse exercício de retorno: Orientação a objetos

Tags: java

```
public class Matematica {

    /*
     * @param um
     * @param dois
     * return o maior dos dois numeros
     * 
     */
    int maior(int um, int dois){            
        if( um  > dois) {               
            return um;
        }
        else {              
            return dois;                
        }
      return 0;
    }
}

public class MatematicaTeste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {            
    }
    Matematica m = new Matematica();
    int maior = m.maior(10, 20);
    System.out.println(maior); //Da Error Aqui, alguém poderia me dizer porque?
}
```

Comment: Leandro, só acertei a formatação para mostrar tudo como um bloco de código (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help). É legal deixar o código com indentação organizada e sem excesso de linhas em branco. É mais fácil para você visualizar a lógica e melhor para quem vai analisar seu código. . . . . Quando fizer uma pergunta, diga exatamente o que e onde não funciona. Mensagens de erro geradas? Saída esperada e saída obtida. Vide [ask].

Comment: Desculpa, sou novo na Zona

Comment: *No problemo*, esqueci de dar as boas vindas ao [pt.so] :) [ps] você é livre para [edit] a pergunta sempre que necessário.

Answer (score 5):

São dois erros:

1º - Na sua classe `Matematica`, tire o `return 0`. 
Não tem porque ele existir ali, uma vez que, se `um > dois`, irá retornar `um`. Se não, retorna `dois`

2º - O outro erro é na sua classe de Teste.

A chamada aos métodos está fora do void main.

Tente assim:

```
public class MatematicaTeste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Matematica m = new Matematica();
        int maior = m.maior(10, 20);
        System.out.println(maior); 
    }

}
```

Sempre que for usar uma classe de teste, coloque as instruções dentro do void main.

Answer (score 4):

Você colocou os comandos fora da `main`. Corrigindo isso e retirando o `return 0` da função `maior()`, rodou normal aqui.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      Matematica m = new Matematica();
      int maior = m.maior(10, 20);
      System.out.println(maior); 
}
```